# Change style of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying create a loop (or use `.each`) to change the `style:display` property of many DOM elements.  My initial thought was to use `getElementsByName` to select all of the elements that I named `ptext1`:

```
<p id="ptext0"name="ptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p id="ptext1"name="ptext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p id="ptext2"name="ptext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p id="ptext3"name="ptext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p id="ptext4"name="ptext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p id="ptext5"name="ptext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p id="ptext6"name="ptext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

using

```
 var TextElements = document.getElementsByName("ptext1");
```

To make an object/array of all of the elements with the name `ptext1`

But I could not get that method working correctly so I moved onto the `.each`.

Both

```
$.each(TextElements, function (index) {
    this.style.display="none";
});
```

and

```
$('td[name=ptext1]').each(function (index) {
    this.style.display="block";
});
```

Didn't seem to work properly (I've been testing whether it runs using alerts).

Now if anyone can see where my mistake is or suggest a better method I am all ears.  This SHOULD be a simple operation but for some reason each time I try, it fails.

Edit:
`$('p[name=ptext1]').hide()` and `$('p[name=ptext1]').show()`
are working except .hide() also hides the line above the ones I would like to hide,

```
<p id="ptext0"name="ptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
```

Each line has a different id tag, but I am trying to use the name tag to keep track of which ones I would like to hide, yet the line that should remain (name="ptext") also hides.

Comment: Might be a copy/paste error, but there is no space before your `name` attribute, which will definately affect the workings of selecting by attribute (aside from the fact `name` is not strictly valid on a `p` element).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you simply use:

```
$('p[name="ptext1"]').css( 'display', 'none');// you can use block...
```

If you want to keep a line shown, exclude that line with `.not()`:

```
$('p[name="ptext1"]').not('#ptext3').css( 'display', 'none');// you can use block...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4JCvt/

And if you just want to use vanilla JavaScript, you can do:

```
var TextElements = document.getElementsByName("ptext1");

for (var i = 0, max = TextElements.length; i < max; i++) {
    TextElements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4JCvt/2/

Comment: Should have quotes around the name- `$('td[name="ptext1"]')` and the element in the OP is `p` not `td`

Comment: Probably does work for the most part, but read the docs (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) - quote: "attribute selectors requre quotes around the attribute value"

Comment: @Jamiec yes i now but if the value is ptext1 it should work also withouth quotes. but i added them anyway :)

Comment: The line I would like to keep displayed already has a different name so theoretically the first example you gave shouldn't affect it, just like .hide shouldn't affect it (yet it does as it gets hidden).  Just to note, I think the plugin I'm using to move the text across the screen (smoothdiv scroll) is messing with the css as the css method does not work, but .hide and .show do.

Comment: @WillGunn if you are using a plugin it might alter everything in your markup, for example it might create it's own tags. That might be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that would be a possibility.  Which is why I originally was trying to do it without jquery (as the plugin is a jquery plugin).  So would you know why creating a loop to go through the elements of TextElements,

`code` for(i=0;i<TextElements.length;i++);
    {
    TextElements[i].style.display="none";
    } `code`
would fail?

Comment: @WillGunn you were not iterating correctly on the collection, like this it works http://jsfiddle.net/4JCvt/2/

Comment: Thanks, As per your edit2, it works just like hide does (it also hides my first line) which I'm not pretty sure is the result of how my scrolling plugin is handling things.  I guess I'll need to figure out a nonstandard fix for a nonstandard issue, but at least I know now that my original thoughts were on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

Use this with JQuery:

```
$("[name='ptext1']").css("display", "value");
//change value to the display value you want
//$("[name='ptext1']").css("display", "block");
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("ptext1");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 elements[i].style.display = "value";
}
//also change value to display value wanted.
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
jQuery("*[name$='ptext1']").css( 'display', 'block');
```

or

```
jQuery("*[name$='ptext1']").css( 'display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, and works with IE8. Just put all your `<p>` elements to `<div>` named "myDiv"

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var y = x.getElementsByTagName("P");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].style.display="none";    }
}
```

- If you want to change all ("*") elements in your `<div>`, use:

  ```
  var y = x.getElementsByTagName("*");
  ```
- If you want to change second `<P>` element in your `<div>`, use:

  ```
  x.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  ```

It's similar to an array.